# Why can’t I use val inside Plugins {}?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```kotlin
val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
plugins {
    // Error: 'val kotlinVersion: String' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary
    kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)]
}
```

I use Kotlin's standard library as a dependency too and I only want to have to specify the version in one place but when I try something like I did above in my build.gradle.kts I get that error you see in the comment. How do I resolve this?

Comment: It works fine for me. Is it related to the square bracket you have at the end -of -the-line?

Answer (score 3):

See [Constrained Syntax](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax) in Gradle documentation:

> The `plugins {}` block does not support arbitrary code. It is constrained, in order to be idempotent (produce the same result every time) and side effect free (safe for Gradle to execute at any time)...

and links to [Plugin Version Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management) to work around it, in your case

```
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id("kotlin").version(kotlinVersion)
  }
}
```

should work I believe.

Or according to

> [Interpolated strings are permitted for PluginDependencySpec.version(String), however replacement values must be sourced from Gradle properties.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html)

It seems if you declare `kotlinVersion` in `gradle.properties` it can be used as

```
version("${kotlinVersion}")
```

in `plugins {}`.

Comment: I tried this and observed that you can access gradle.properties in the buildSrc and module build.gradle.kts, but not in the root build.gradle.kts

Comment: I declared in `gradle.properties` but it won't work.